# How to pass a value from one Application to another in Android?

Tags: android

Can any one tell me how to pass data through bundle or any thing else between two installed applications in android?

I have googled around but could not get any proper guide.

In first Application I have the following code for transferring the value "withdrawl" to another .

```
Intent fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent.putExtra("source",
                    "withdrawal");
            // fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            // fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent.setComponent(new
            // ComponentName("com.integratedbiometrics.SimpleScan",
            // "com.integratedbiometrics.SimpleScan.SimpleScanActivity"));
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager
                    .queryIntentActivities(
                            fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent, 0);
            boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
            if (isIntentSafe) {

                startActivityForResult(
                        fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent,
                        Constants.FINGER_PRINT_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_WITHDRAWAL);
            } else {
                Log.i("No Such Activity Found",
                        "No Such Activity Found To Open.");
                ShowToastMessage("No FingerPrint Device is available.");
            }
```

On 2nd Application , I have tested whether it receives the string "withdrawl" . If It receives , it will set layout to activity_verify . The code of it is the following :

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey("withdrawal"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);
            requestPurpose = REQUEST_PURPOSE.TAKE_SINGLE_FINGER_PRINT; 
        }
        else
        {  
            requestPurpose = REQUEST_PURPOSE.TAKE_FOUR_FINGER_PRINT;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register); 
        }
```

I have sent  "withdrawl" from first application to 2nd . But 2nd application is launched with activity_register layout . Why ? Can you help me PLease ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `withdrawal` string is a value - not a key. There is no search in bundle for value. Change your `if` condition to `bundle.containsKey("source")`.

May be you need `bundle.getString("source").equals("withdrawal")`.